# Matching CSS Selectors with a Javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, css, regex, css-selectors

Basically I need to pattern match any and all CSS selectors in a CSS file. Ideally it should be able to grab all of these rules (and any other rule someone could make up in a CSS file). This is for a javascript CSS parser if that helps at all.

```
#div div .child {

}

.somediv, #someotherdiv {

}

body:hover {

}
```

The best i've been able to come up with so far is something like:

```
/(#|\.|[a-zA-Z])(.*) {/g
```

But this just ends up selecting more than what it needs to... Like one selector, all it's rules, and the up to the next selector's opening "{". Been trying for hours with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just concerned about the selectors themselves, this should get you a little closer.  I think it is matching single spaces, so could use a little more tweaking yet...

```
var css = ...some css string...
var found = css.replace(/{([^}]*)}/gm,"{}").match(/([#|\.]?)([\w|:|\s|\.]+)/gmi);
```

Comment: This worked awesomely. All I had to add was a quick "{" at the end it it's working. Thanks a bunch, man.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to a lazy star and try again:

```
/(#|\.|[a-zA-Z])(.*?) {/g
```

That way it won't be greedy.

Comment: This isn't the regex that I need, but your lazy star helped with another regexp I had to make. So +1 for you sir!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do brace-matching, you need a language more descriptive than what plain old regex provides. http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html has some examples of what different programming languages have come up with to deal with the "named group" problem.

You'll need a parser, not just regex for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing .* with negated character class?

```
/(#|\.|[a-zA-Z])([^{]*) {/g
```