# How to parse and extract CSS selectors as strings?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, css-selectors

What is the simplest way to extract css selectors as strings?

Given this as input:

```
#article{width:690px;overflow:hidden}
#article h2:first-child a{text-decoration:none}
#works .project p:last-child{margin-top:20px;font-size:13px}
#works .project img, #works .info img{width:680px;min-height:400px;border:1px dotted #ccc;margin-bottom:40px}
```

How can I get a list of selectors such as this:

```
var selectors = ['#article','#article h2:first-child a','#works .project p:last-child','#works .project img']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS parser/abstracter? How to convert stylesheet into object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226869/css-parser-abstracter-how-to-convert-stylesheet-into-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching CSS Selectors with a Javascript RegExp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481749/matching-css-selectors-with-a-javascript-regexp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up with:

1. Replace the curly braces including its contents with some unique characters. Regex was picked up from here [Matching CSS Selectors with a Javascript RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226869/css-parser-abstracter-how-to-convert-stylesheet-into-object)
2. Split the list at those unique characters.

Just wanted to post it here for documention:

```
var css = "#article[type=x]{width:690px;overflow:hidden}#article h2:first-child a{text-decoration:none}#works .project p:last-child{margin-top:20px;font-size:13px}#works .project img, #works .info img{width:680px;min-height:400px;border:1px dotted #ccc;margin-bottom:40px}"
var found = css.replace(/{([^}]*)}/gm,"~~~").split("~~~");

document.write(found);
```

Answer (score 2):

Define "input. If that's in a stylesheet that's been parsed by the browser, you can use the [DOM Level 2 Style](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/) APIs to extract the CSS rules in your stylesheet and query them for selectors (though you may have to do comma-splitting yourself).

If it's not parsed by the browser but is provided as input via some other mechanism, you might be able to use [JSCSSP](http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/) (a CSS parser in JavaScript) to parse the input.

Comment: Its a string of CSS that the user has provided.

Comment: @kht: Then it sounds like JSCSSP is probably the solution you want.

Comment: Perhaps, doesn't it seem overkill though just to extract css selectors?

Comment: @kht: Ehh, maybe. The answer for [Matching CSS Selectors with a Javascript RegExp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481749/matching-css-selectors-with-a-javascript-regexp) might work for you, though I'm always a bit skeptical about people using regexps for parsing. There's probably edge cases that the regexp won't handle, but JSCSSP will (since it implements a proper parser).

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: Waporcode, I haven't tested this, but I've used something like this before....

```
    document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].selectorText
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: IE does it differently. *sigh* see: http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/IE_wont_allow_documentcreateElementstyle.html

Comment: The CSS will be user input, so the CSS is basically a string that needs to be parsed.